# Getting different errors with import types and slice in react-redux and redux toolkit

Tags: reactjs, redux, error-handling, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm new to redux in react and i was trying to find my foot by building a to-do list application, and when i use my reducers i get different errors, here is my code

For SLICE.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const todoSlice = createSlice({
    name: "todo",
    initialState: [
        { id: 1, title: "Learn React", completed: true },
        { id: 2, title: "Learn Redux", completed: false },
        { id: 3, title: "Learn React-Redux", completed: false },
        { id: 4, title: "Learn React-Router", completed: false }],
    reducer: {
        addTodo: (state, action) => {
            const newTodo = {
                id: Math.random(),
                title: action.payload.title,
                completed: false
            };
            state.push(newTodo)
        },
        deleteTodo: (state, action) => {
            state.filter((todo) => todo.id !== action.payload.id)
        }
    }
}
)

export const { addTodo, deleteTodo } = todoSlice.actions;
export default todoSlice.reducer
```

for Store,

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import todoRedcuer from './todoSlice'
export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
        todo: todoRedcuer
    }
});
```

now whenever i want to use these reducers in their respective components, I get different errors with different import type
for example,

```
import addTodo from "../redux/todoSlice";
```

for this import type, i get this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'type')

and for this import type,

```
import { addTodo }from "../redux/todoSlice";
```

i get this error

> List.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , *redux_todoSlice__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2*_.addTodo) is not a function

This is the component where i'm dispatching the code

```
import React from "react";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import addTodo from "../redux/todoSlice";

const TodoForm = () => {
    const [Todo, setTodo] = React.useState();
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        dispatch(
            addTodo({
                title: Todo,
            })
        );
    };

    return (
        <div className="flex items-center flex-col justify-center">
            <h1 className="my-8">To-Do List</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    name="todo"
                    placeholder="Add todo..."
                    value={Todo}
                    onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
                    className="px-6 py-3 rounded-xl outline-0 bg-slate-100 mr-10"
                />
                <button
                    className="px-6 py-3 rounded-xl outline-0 bg-blue-500"
                >
                    Add..
                </button>
            </form>
            <h3>{Todo}</h3>
        </div>
    );
};

export default TodoForm;
```

What am i getting wrong or missing please?
Thanks for your time and assistance

Answer (score 1):

In your line

```js
import addTodo from "../redux/todoSlice";
// this is a shortcut for
import { default as addTodo } from "../redux/todoSlice";
```

you are actually importing your slice reducer, not the action.

Do this instead:

```js
import { addTodo } from "../redux/todoSlice";
```

Comment: I understand this, but when I use `import { addTodo } from "../redux/todoSlice";`  I get this error ` Uncaught TypeError: (0 , redux_todoSlice__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_.addTodo) is not a function`

Comment: Per comment over on Reddit: it looks like you're passing an object named `reducer` into `createSlice`, but it needs to be **`reducers`** (with an 's')